# Manual Collision Detection in Lua

Tags: lua, collision-detection, collision, coronasdk

So Im working on a simple rectangle rectangle collision for my game in Lua.  I have an algorithm i was using for other projects for this type of collision but its in C++ and I know it works.  The issue is that it uses the center of the rectangle.  While easy to calculate im having issues keeping the center, in the center as the sprite is moving.  Here what Im doing

```
--this moves the bounding box of the collision, BUT not the center

self.boundingBox.sprite.tween = transition.to(self.boundingBox.sprite,{ transistion = easing.outExpo, y = arg.y, x=arg.x,time = arg.time,onComplete = function() end});
```

The sprite is moving like it should but the property "self.boundingBox.centerY" isn't and Im not sure what would be the best way to handle this situation. please help Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get position of an object in transition. That can be problematic. I recommend you to use enterFrame event listener and update object's positions manually. In that way, you can handle with collisions more effectively

Answer (score 0):

The code does not seem to move self.boundingBox at all since the parameter to transition.to is self.boundingBox.sprite.

If the boundingBox is a group that contains sprite then you could just change self.boundingBox.sprite to self.boundingBox and both should be moved.
Otherwise you would need to check the sprite for property change instead of the boundingBox.